# Hubot Heroku route message on startup

Tags: heroku, hubot, slack-api

I have deployed a Hubot on Heroku to interact with Slack. I am using a free dyno currently. After 30 minutes of inactivity, it goes to sleep. It wakes up when pinged from Slack. However, the first request is lost in the mix. So the user has to type the command a second time. Is there an easy way to make the bot wake up and still handle the first command?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://hubot.github.com/docs/deploying/heroku/) :

> To get around this, you can use the [hubot-heroku-keepalive](https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-heroku-keepalive) script, which will keep your free dyno alive for up to 18 hours/day. If you never want Hubot to sleep, you will need to upgrade to Heroku's hobby plan.

I use it so Hubot is at least online from 6 AM to midnight.